# Why use "#" in querys in an XML file?

Tags: java, xml, oracle

Currently , I'm working on project where they have a xml file where they store all querys but there are a querys which use the following syntax :

```
FROM [tables]
   WHERE     [t.field1] = [s.field2]
          AND dh.id_unidad_cr = dd.id_unidad_cr
          AND dh.folio_sol_83 = dd.folio_sol_83
          AND doc_haplicado IN ('1', '2')
          AND ##CCOP_163#IN##
          AND ##DH_DOC_SOL_PAGO.ID_UNIDAD_CR#IN##
          AND ##DH_DOC_SOL_PAGO.SPAG_72#=##
          AND ##TRUNC(DH_DOC_SOL_PAGO.FECHA_APL)#BETWEEN##
```

I don´t understand, which is the function of #?

Comment: What processes the XML and queries the DB? Looks like some kind of placeholder mechanism.

Comment: They are likely replacement markers for some homegrown SQL building framework.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, Could you give me an example? I do not know how it works